# How can I parse a month and a year without a date in Java?

Tags: java, date, parsing

I tried it like this

```
public LocalDate parseDate(String date) {
    return LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-yyyy"));
}
```

but this code throw an exception

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=5, Year=2022},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Comment: I would suggest parsing to `YearMonth` instead, given that that's what your data actually represents. I'd also use `uuuu` instead of `yyyy` so that it's "absolute year" instead of "year of era".

Comment: Prepend a 1 and parse as an ordinary date.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I’d frankly consider that misuse. Just like you shouldn’t use a `double` for holding an integer nor a `LocalDateTime` for holding a date, you also should not use a `LocalDate` for holding a month.

Comment: @OleV.V.: your comment is irrelevant. The question is about parsing the date (for some unknown purpose) and I did not advise any format for "holding" it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `YearMonth`

You cannot create a `LocalDate` having a month of year and the year only, it just needs a day of month (and does not provide any default value).

Since you are trying to parse a `String` of the format `"MM-uuuu"`, I assume you are not interested in creating a `LocalDate`, which inevitably boils down to the use of a [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

Example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // an arbitrary mont of year
    String strMay2022 = "05-2022";
    // prepare the formatter in order to parse it
    DateTimeFormatter ymDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-uuuu");
    // then parse it to a YearMonth
    YearMonth may2022 = YearMonth.parse(strMay2022, ymDtf);
    // if necessary, define the day of that YearMonth to get a LocalDate
    LocalDate may1st2022 = may2022.atDay(1);
    // print something meaningful concerning the topic…
    System.out.println(may1st2022 + " is the first day of " + may2022);
}
```

Output:

```
2022-05-01 is the first day of 2022-05
```